# How can we check if Email has been synced already in Email Applications Pane of Outlook Office 365?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, office-365, lightning-outlook, email-application-pane

I'm trying to get through with the newly introduced functionality of being able to put a custom Lightning Component in `Email Applications Pane` in `Lightning for Outlook` - [Create Components for Lightning for Outlook (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_email_app_pane.htm)

The documentation is very limited and only provides information of an Email or Event being in Context, which is good info but what I was also looking for is, **how to check if the selected Email has already been synced to a Record in linked Salesforce org**?

I mean, usually in these synced activities there is an ID stored somewhere on the Email record in Salesforce, we could query that out but I don't know which field it is stored in or if there is some other way to gather this information?